# Remove duplicate objects in array based on value keeping only the newest (based on second value of timestamp)

Tags: php, arrays

```
[
    {
        title: "Item 1",
        dateModified: 1598208392600
    },
    {
        title: "Item 1",
        dateModified: 1598208395105
    },
    {
        title: "Item 1",
        dateModified: 1598210504648
    },
    {
        title: "Item 2",
        dateModified: 1598210604491
    },
    {
        title: "Item 2",
        dateModified: 1598210612439
    }
]
```

How can I return a new array containing only one "Item 1" and one "Item 2", where the items kept are the ones with the newest timestamp?

Been seeing a bunch of similar questions but haven't found anything I could make work or that fits my situation properly.

Comment: These are arrays or objects inside?

Comment: Objects inside array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a single foreach and comparison of timestamps should be enough to achieve this:

```
<?php

$data = [
    (object)[
        'title' => "Item 1",
        'dateModified' => 1598208392600
    ],
    (object)[
        'title' => "Item 1",
        'dateModified' => 1598208395105
    ],
    (object)[
        'title' => "Item 1",
        'dateModified' => 1598210504648
    ],
    (object)[
        'title' => "Item 2",
        'dateModified' => 1598210604491
    ],
    (object)[
        'title' => "Item 2",
        'dateModified' => 1598210612439
    ],
];

$filtered = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
  if (!isset($filtered[$row->title])) {
    $filtered[$row->title] = $row;
  }

  if ($filtered[$row->title]->dateModified < $row->dateModified) {
    $filtered[$row->title] = $row;
  }
}

var_dump($filtered);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["Item 1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "Item 1"
    ["dateModified"]=>
    int(1598210504648)
  }
  ["Item 2"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "Item 2"
    ["dateModified"]=>
    int(1598210612439)
  }
}
```